# I can't remove space when get value from xml using node.getTextContent()

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have xml configuration file that we parsed using DOM parser.when i get value from childnode using node.getTextContent();,i cannot remove space in the string value.it works when i give value without space. but, i have to handle negative scenerio too.

I tried trim(),replaceAll("\s", "") and replaceAll("\u00A0", "");but nothing worked for me

```
 NodeList serviceAddrNodeList=serviceAddressesNode.getChildNodes();

 packetSendingIplist =new ArrayList();

 for (int l = 0; l < serviceAddrNodeList.getLength(); l++) {

   Node serviceAddrNode=serviceAddrNodeList.item(l);

   if(serviceAddrNode.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){                                                                        

    String packetSendingIp = serviceAddrNode.getTextContent();                                                  
    packetSendingIp.trim(); //replaceAll("\s", "") and replaceAll("\u00A0", "")                      
    if(checkValidIp(packetSendingIp)){

      log("invalid service_addr-"+packetSendingIp+"ignoring this 
      listening point ");   
   }
 }                                                   
}
```

xml:

```
  <service_addresses>
  <!-- host1 -->
  <service_addr>172.17.1.16 </service_addr>
  <service_addr>172.17.1.17 </service_addr>
  <!-- host12-->
  <service_addr>172.17.1.32</service_addr>//works becuase no space here
  <service_addr>172.17.1.33 </service_addr>    
</service_addresses>
```

Comment: Where in your code you try to do Trim() or replaceAll ?

Comment: "I tried trim(),replaceAll("\s", "") and replaceAll("\u00A0", "");but nothing worked for me". Have you assigned the result of these operations back to `packetSendingIp`or have you just called it? If the latter, do the former.

Comment: @Lothar sir i updated my code

Comment: @RafałSokalski  sir i updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
File fXmlFile = new File("your xml file path");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("service_addr");
   for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent().trim());
   }
```

output, without any whitespaces

```
172.17.1.16
172.17.1.17
172.17.1.32
172.17.1.33
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the whitespaces on the beginning and end of the content through a regex:

```
public class Main {

    public static final String DEST = "html_1.pdf";
    private static final String WHITESPACE_REGEX = "(^( )*|( )*$)";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals(" 192.168.1.1 ".replaceAll(WHITESPACE_REGEX, StringUtils.EMPTY), "192.168.1.1");
        Assert.assertEquals("     192.168.1.1 ".replaceAll(WHITESPACE_REGEX, StringUtils.EMPTY), "192.168.1.1");
        Assert.assertEquals("192.168.1.1         ".replaceAll(WHITESPACE_REGEX, StringUtils.EMPTY), "192.168.1.1");
        Assert.assertEquals("192.168.1.1".replaceAll(WHITESPACE_REGEX, StringUtils.EMPTY), "192.168.1.1");
    }
}
```

Comment: bro,ip will be dynamically given.In your example, should match with unspaced ip with ip which is received from xml??  thanks for your reply

Comment: Hey there, the regex will remove the spaces from the beginning and end of any text you pass to it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do Trim() like that. You have to assign this output again to variable because after what you doing it will have still The same value. Add trim to this line and it should works as expected.

```
String packetSendingIp = serviceAddrNode.getTextContent().trim()
```

Comment: Exactly sir.i just figured out and you answerd it. thanks